# How to make a PHP XML/RPC call to UPC database

Tags: php, xml, xml-rpc

hay i am working on barcode reader project when i call upcdatabase from my php script it give me errors. i use the php example provided by [www.upcdatabase.com](http://www.upcdatabase.com)

the code is

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

 require_once 'XML/RPC.php';

 $rpc_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Set your rpc_key here
 $upc='0639382000393';
 // Setup the URL of the XML-RPC service
 $client = new XML_RPC_Client('/xmlrpc', 'http://www.upcdatabase.com');
 $params = array( new XML_RPC_Value( array(
  'rpc_key' => new XML_RPC_Value($rpc_key, 'string'),
  'upc' => new XML_RPC_Value($upc, 'string'),
  ), 'struct'));
 $msg = new XML_RPC_Message('lookup', $params);
 $resp = $client->send($msg);
 if (!$resp)
            {
  echo 'Communication error: ' . $client->errstr;
  exit;
 }
 if(!$resp->faultCode())
 {
  $val = $resp->value();
  $data = XML_RPC_decode($val);
  echo "<pre>" . print_r($data, true) . "</pre>";
 }else{
  echo 'Fault Code: ' . $resp->faultCode() . "\n";
  echo 'Fault Reason: ' . $resp->faultString() . "\n";
 }
?>
```

when i check the $upc='0639382000393'; into upc data base [view this](http://www.upcdatabase.com/itemform.asp) then it works fine but i run this script into the browser then it give the following error

```
Array
(
    [status] => fail
    [message] => Invalid UPC length
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, their API appears rather short on documentation.

There are three types of codes the site mentions on the [Item Lookup page](http://www.upcdatabase.com/itemform.asp):

- 13 digits for an EAN/UCC-13
- 12 digits for a Type A UPC code, or
- 8 digits for a Type-E (zero-supressed) UPC code.

Right after the page mentions those three types, it also says,

> Anything other than 8 or 12 digits is **not** a UPC code!

The [13-digit EAN/UCC-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Article_Number) is a superset of [UPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code). It includes valid UPCs, but it has many other values that are not valid UPCs.

From [the Wikipedia article on EAN-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Article_Number#Binary_encoding_of_data_digits_into_EAN-13_barcode):

> If the first digit is zero, all digits in the first group of six are encoded using the patterns used for UPC, hence a UPC barcode is also an EAN-13 barcode with the first digit set to zero.

Having said that, when I removed the leading zero from `$upc`, it worked as expected. Apparently the Item Lookup page has logic to remove the leading zero, while the API does not.

```
Array
(
    [upc] => 639382000393
    [pendingUpdates] => 0
    [status] => success
    [ean] => 0639382000393
    [issuerCountryCode] => us
    [found] => 1
    [description] => The Teenager's Guide to the Real World by BYG Publishing
    [message] => Database entry found
    [size] => book
    [issuerCountry] => United States
    [noCacheAfterUTC] => 2011-01-22T14:46:15
    [lastModifiedUTC] => 2002-08-23T23:07:36
)
```

Alternatively, instead of setting the `upc` param, you can set the original 13-digit value to the `ean` param and it will also work.